# CSS Doesn't Link To HTML

Tags: html, css

My CSS file does not response to HTML file. I have imported the CSS file in my HTML file and both files are in the same directory. It previously worked when my CSS and HTML were in written in the same file. However, when I try to separate both files, the CSS file fails to respond.

```css
<head><style>body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}


/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/

ul {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}


/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/

li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
}


/*Style for menu links*/

li a {
  display: block;
  width: 528px;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2f3036;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*Hover state for top level links*/

li:hover a {
  background: #DEB887;
}


/*Style for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  color: #2f3036;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}


/*Hover state for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a:hover {
  background: #19c589;
  color: #fff;
}


/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/

li ul {
  display: none;
}


/*Make dropdown links vertical*/

li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}


/*Prevent text wrapping*/

li ul li a {
  width: auto;
  width: 488px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}


/*Display the dropdown on hover*/

ul li a:hover+.hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block;
}


/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/

.show-menu {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #19c589;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: none;
}


/*Hide checkbox*/

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}


/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#menu {
  display: block;
}


/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
  ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
  }
  /*Create vertical spacing*/
  li {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
  }
  /*Make all menu links full width*/
  ul li,
  li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*Display 'show menu' link*/
  .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}

</style></head>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!--Importing CSS file-->

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
</head>
<!--End of import-->

<body>

  <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">VCT Operation</a>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">Conduct Operation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">View Reports</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where your css file located? ...

Comment: Run your CSS file through a CSS validator or linter, such as https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using HTML syntax inside the CSS file.

You have to replace the below syntax:

```
<head><style>body {
   background-color: lightblue;
}

...
...
...

</style></head>
```

with:

```
body{
  background-color: lightblue;
}

...
...
...

/* remove the closing tags*/
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<head><style>body {
```

The `.css` file isn't HTML. It's just pure CSS.

Remove the `<head><style>` from the beginning of your CSS file, as well as the matching "closing tags".

Answer (score 2):

Your external css file contains `<head>` and `<style>` tag which is Incorrect. External stylesheets only contain CSS. For example:

```
 body {
  background-color: lightblue;
 }


 /*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/

  ul {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  }
  .
  .
```

`<head><style> ......</head></style>` tag inside an HTML file is used to define internal styles.

Comment: Same happened on my answer, upvoting yours for the sake of humanity.

Comment: It is not that it is not **required**, it is not **allowed**, which means something different. This question is essentially about a kind of typo, which is a reason to close and/or comment, not answer. If you really want to answer, then you need to provide the OP with guidance about how to find such errors in the future, and/or references to relevant documentation.

Comment: @torazaburo Answer edited. Maybe in the jiffy of answering I wrote `required` while a more correct word would be `invalid`. But even with `not required` it is not completely incorrect. Anyways, I guess a simple comment would suffice. I don't understand why people start acting all grammar nazi, syntax nazi on SO. Thats the reason I spend lesser time on SO and more on other platforms. I pointed out OP's mistake, gave him correction, more than enough I guess. If you feel the need to provide guidance and ref for such small errors then you are free to give some time and post an answer of your own.

Answer (score 2):

Your css file does not need the `<head><style>` and `</body></html>` tags. Remove those and it should work